# Array/List that can Grow in two directions?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

Ok so here is my Goal:

- An Array that I can expand at the end end the beginning without messing up the indices
- A object that was input at index 3 should remain at index 3 even if I want to add a new object
  at position '-1' (-1 being the position before the initial start position)
- There can be empty Cells in the Array which could be filled later

What I thought of so far:

- Using Dictionaries with strings

  - probably to inefficient parsing between string and number all the time
- Using an Offset and just making the Array Bigger

  - I think this would result in creating a lot of arrays which sounds very inefficient

    - Maybe some smarter algorithm to increase array size would work (doubling it/increasing it by 25 instead of 1)
- Using two Arrays one for positive values one for negative ones

  - Seems pretty hard to work with when near position Zero

What do I need this for:
I want to make a game where the 2D grid based world can be expanded by the player and things like the tiles around a new placed tile are very important (kind of  a mix between dorfromantik and Islanders)

Comment: "Using Directories with strings" - What? Do you mean `Dictionary`?

Comment: Have a property of your class that contains the index.   Start the index at 1,000,000.   Worry about performance later/never.

Comment: And what do you mean by "probably to inefficient parsing between string and number all the time"?

Comment: What about having a `List` and either use [`Add(item)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Add__0_) to append the items at the end or [`Insert(0, item)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Insert_System_Int32__0_) to prepand items at the beginning?

Comment: Hi. For this assignment I think you should consider Linked List or maybe two way linked list. You can append, prepend and you don't have to worry about performance that much. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list

Comment: The question is? Do you still need to access the elements by their index? (also for the comment of @Klemikaze)

Comment: Yes i meant Dictionaries.
I think just not worrying about performance will end badly.
Yes i do still need to access the elements by their index.

Comment: Would it be troublesome to insert objects at a specific not end or beginning position with a double linked list?

Comment: `I think just not worrying about performance will end badly.` so will writing complex lists to solve a performance problem you don't know exists. It costs absolutely nothing to just start with a `List<T>` and implement another storage mechanism later if `List<T>` is too slow. You can even create your own repository class and add an interface so you can easily swap the list repository out for a different one later.

Comment: My [`CircularList<T>`](http://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Collections_CircularList_1.htm) actually does something similar: it does not shift all items when inserting/removing at index 0. On the other hand, it does not assign negative indices for items inserted at the beginning so it is functionally compatible with `List<T>`. If this is OK for you, then [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) is the NuGet link (where you find also the GitHub link if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this fully nor implement every method, but here's one approach:

```
public class TwoEndedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> _natural = new List<T>();
    private List<T> _negative = new List<T>();

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => index < 0 ? _negative[-index - 1] : _natural[index];
        set
        {
            if (index < 0)
                _negative[-index - 1] = value;
            else
                _natural[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count => _natural.Count + _negative.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _natural.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddLast(T item)
    {
        _natural.Add(item);
    }
    public void AddFirst(T item)
    {
        _negative.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _natural.Clear();
        _negative.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) => _natural.Contains(item) || _negative.Contains(item);

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (var i = _negative.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return _negative[i];
        for (var i = 0; i < _natural.Count; i++)
            yield return _natural[i];
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        var index = _natural.IndexOf(item);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            index = -1 - _negative.IndexOf(item);
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var tel = new TwoEndedList<int>();

tel.Add(4);
tel.Add(5);
tel.AddFirst(1);
tel.AddFirst(2);

foreach (var x in tel)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

Console.WriteLine(tel[-2]);
Console.WriteLine(tel[-1]);
Console.WriteLine(tel.IndexOf(2));
```

That gives me:

```
2
1
4
5
2
1
-2
```

Comment: Yeah that is close to what i am using atm even tho your implementation looks a lot cleaner

Comment: Also i am using an array because there is the possibility of having "empty spaces" between objects

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using a Dictionary. Hopefully it can give you some ideas

```
Dictionary<Vector2, object> map = new Dictionary<Vector2, object>();
int mapSize;

void Start()
{
    GenerateMap(8); // 8 = number of rows and columns

    UpdateTileValue(new Vector2(0, 0), "Here's my house"); //set the value of a specific tile

    ExpandMap(1); //add another layer to the map surface
}

private void GenerateMap(int size)
{
    mapSize = size;
    int lowerBound = Mathf.FloorToInt(mapSize / 2f);
    int upperBound = Mathf.CeilToInt(mapSize / 2f);

    for (int row = -lowerBound; row < upperBound; row++)
    {
        for (int column = -lowerBound; column < upperBound; column++)
        {
            Vector2 address = new Vector2(row, column);
            
            if (!map.ContainsKey(address))
                map.Add(address, null);
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateTileValue(Vector2 address, object value)
{
    if (map.ContainsKey(address))
        map[address] = value;
}

private void ExpandMap(int numLayers) => GenerateMap(mapSize + numLayers);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch i am currently trying to use just a 2 dimensional array with an offset but if the math gets too Spagetti i will probably fall back to this solution ^^